# Convert SystemIcons into ImageList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I try to convert `System.Drawing.SystemIcons` to `System.Windows.Forms.ImageList` for using it in a `ListView`

I try the following code :

```
ImageList iconlist = new ImageList();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(SystemIcons).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(property.Name);
   iconlist.Images.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(SystemIcons).ToBitmap());
}
```

But it's return : 'SystemIcons' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: You should specify the color depth and size, as in `ImageList iconlist = new ImageList() { ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit, ImageSize = new Size(16,16) };`, otherwise the result could be quite poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get the value of a static property, you have to pass `null` as the instance. Additionally, `GetValue()` returns an `object`, so you have to cast it:

```
iconlist.Images.Add(property.Name, (Icon)property.GetValue(null));
```

Thankfully, `ImageCollection.Add()` already has an overload that takes an icon, so no need for `ToBitmap()`.